# Google map in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to implement Google map in my ASP.NET MVC3 application. i already have Google map code and i want to add Get Direction for any specific City or Country, means i want to add a text-Box in View(HTML) where is enter the "Delhi" and click the GetDirection button then map will show the Delhi in India Map.

my Google Map Code in View(Razor) is below:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Google Map";
}
@section Scripts { 
    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
} 
@section Styles { 
    html { height: 100% } 
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } 
    #map_canvas { height: 80% } 
} 

<h2>Google Maps</h2>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() 
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
        var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
    }
    $(function () {
        initialize();
    }); 

</script>
```

so help to add the GetDirection on my application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate a place on the map depending on the location name, you will need the Geocoding service- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Have a reading of the documentation for Geocoding and you will be able to achieve what you are looking for.